# Assertion Failed getting External Data from SQL Server

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, excel-2010

When I select from the Ribbon **Get External Data -> From SQL Server** I get the following Assertion Failed dialog from EXCEL:
    [image]

I have tried this with an Admin account, and after logging off and on, with the same results. If I select **-> From Analysis Services** I don't get the dialog.

f I choose **Ignore** I get a dialog to specify *connection details* but it always fails, reporting an inability to locate the server, even though in SSMS and through TFS I can connect to the server without issues. The DB server is my local machine, though a Named Instance.
(Yes, I have very carefully checked that the server name is correctly specified.)

Has anyone seen this before and can assist in diagnosing the issue?

**Update**:

The error dialog occurs immediately on clicking on *From SQL Server*.

If I opt to **Retry** from the dialog, I get the standard *Microsoft Excel has stopped working, would you like to check online for a solution etc.* dialog. If I attempt to debug the code I am informed that Source is not available, although symbols appear to be successfully downloaded form the Microsoft Symbol Server.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you get the error as soon as you click "From SQL Server?" (I have never seen this before so won't be able to help)

Comment: @DougGlancy: Yes, the error dialog occurs immediately on clicking on *From SQL Server*.